# How to add all numbers in txt file and make into a variable with a value?

Tags: php, html, math, logging, addition

Basically, I'm trying to make it where when the button is pressed, it will log `1` into data.txt then PHP will add up the `1`'s and display that number for all users on-page to see. I'm trying to do this in complete PHP but I can use javascript and HTML if needed. Here is my complete code:

```
<?php

$newline = "\n";
$filename = 'data.txt';
$somecontent = ("1");


if (is_writable($filename)) {



    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    if (fwrite($handle, "$somecontent $newline") === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }


    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>__Work-In-Progress__</title>
    </head>
    <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = post>
    <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "Submit" >
</form>
</html>
```

It's kinda messy but ahh it gets the job done. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Site is here but I'm not finished with the CSS and all.>>
http://clickthebutton.rf.gd/index.php

Comment: After writing to the file, get the content of the file again then use `explode("\n", $content)` to get the number of 1 in the file. And use a loop now to sum everything. Since it is only `1` you are writing, you can just count the array and that gives you exactly the sum.

Comment: Also you can `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` to deal simply with files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep i got it! Here is my full code:

```
<?php

$newline = "\n";
$filename = 'data.txt';
$somecontent = ("1");


if (is_writable($filename)) {



    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    if (fwrite($handle, "$somecontent $newline") === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }


    fclose($handle);

} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}

$no_of_lines = count(file($filename)); 
 
echo "The button has been pressed $no_of_lines times."

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>__Work-In-Progress__</title>
    </head>
    <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = post>
    <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "Submit" >
</form>
</html>
```